# Creating number of template fields dynamically using a loop and creating Item Template for each template field

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view, which should get create template fields using a loop. This loop will have a list of items which count is not constant. And I wanted to create Item Template for each template field. Below is my code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvMydata" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CssClass="dataTable"
                meta:resourcekey="gvPreSeedResultResource1"
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd">
```

In code behind page

```
 List<PList> pList = new List<ProjectList>();

            pList = GetDetails();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ServerGroup", typeof(string));
            TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
            tf.HeaderText = "ServerGroup";
            gvPreSeedResult.Columns.Add(tf);
            foreach (PList pl in pList)
            {
                TemplateField tf1 = new TemplateField();
                tf1.HeaderText = pl.Id.ToString();
                gvPreSeedResult.Columns.Add(tf1);

                //dt.Columns.Add(pl.ProjectId.ToString(),typeof(string));
            }
            DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "ADC";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    gvMydata.DataSource = dt;
            gvMydata.DataBind();
```

Comment: Very well. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Yes, But I failed. As I only know how to create template field dynamically but again to assign values to the ItemTemplate how I need to create that and how I need to get those values? I did not understand that is the reason I posted this question

Comment: SO is for getting answers to specific questions. So what you should do to maximize the likelihood of someone helping you, is to post your failed attempt in the question, and say exactly what part of it you are struggling with. In the current form your question looks like "please write some code for me"